# How to calculate the buoyance's work when releasing bar above water

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

The exercise is to calculate the buoyance's work when releasing a bar of mass $m$, lenght $L$ and cross section area $S$  just above water. My problem is that I am assuming my referencial on the water surface and looking to the buoyance's center of application. This way its height variation is of $L/2$, so I am finding half of the answear and can't see why my thinking doesn't work. The image shows some of my work:

[image]

$$W_E=\int^{L/2}_0E(x)\cdot x=\int^{L/2}_0\rho g S\cdot 2x\  \mathrm{d}x=\bigg[2\rho gS\frac{x^2}{2}\bigg]^{L/2}_0$$
$$\Rightarrow W_E=\rho g S \frac{L^2}{4}$$

Comment: Can you please show more work? Like what values you got and your thinking behind it?

Comment: I edited my text, showing what I tried.

Comment: Please don't post formulas as pictures or plain text, but use MathJax instead. MathJax is easy for people on all devices to read, and can show up clearer on different screen sizes and resolutions. I've edited it here as an example. Look at [this Math SE meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) for a quick tutorial.

Comment: There are multiple methods. For instance: integrate force $\times$ distance, in which case the distance is how far the bar moves (L, not L/2); or integrate $P dV$. Either way gives an answer twice as large as yours.

Comment: But why is my thinking wrong? Knowing the answear, why is it wrong to consider the buoyance's center of application as I did?